# Captcha image is not displayed on localhost

Tags: php, captcha

I have designed a simple contact form for a WordPress theme and used a simple captcha image inside the form.

My main problem is that the captcha image is not generated.

I have installed the GD library for **xampp** software (**on localhost**) but still the captcha image is not displayed and when I right-click and select the inspect option in the  tag, I get the following line:
`<img height="80" width="200" src="captcha/captcha.php"/>`

I have tried similar codes and other captcha libraries but still the captcha image is not displayed to me.

I searched a lot and didn't find a solution to display captcha image on localhost.

Can the captcha image be displayed in localhost and I am not looking for something impossible?

Note: My contact form is fine and only the captcha image is not displayed.

The code I put in `index.php`:

```
<!-- Start your project here-->
<div class="container">
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <!-- Default form contact -->
            <form autocomplete="off" class="text-center border border-light p-5" method="post" action="submitform.php">
                <p class="h4 mb-4">Contact us</p>
                <!-- Name -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" name="family" placeholder="name">
                <!-- Phone -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" name="phone" placeholder="phone">
                <!-- Email -->
                <input type="email" class="form-control mb-4" name="email" placeholder="email">
                <!-- Message -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <!-- Capthca -->
                <img height="80" width="200" src="captcha/captcha.php"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" name="captcha" placeholder="Enter the security code">
                <!-- Send button -->
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" name="btn" type="submit">submit</button>
            </form>
            <!-- Default form contact -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code I put in `submitform.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['captcha'] === $_POST['captcha']) {
    echo 'The security code is correct.';
} else {
    echo 'Security code is wrong.';
}
```

The code I put in `captcha.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
//You can customize your captcha settings here

$captcha_code = '';
$captcha_image_height = 50;
$captcha_image_width = 130;
$total_characters_on_image = 6;

//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid all confusing characters and numbers (For example: l, 1 and i)
$possible_captcha_letters = 'bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz23456789';
$captcha_font = './monofont.ttf';

$random_captcha_dots = 50;
$random_captcha_lines = 25;
$captcha_text_color = "0x142864";
$captcha_noise_color = "0x142864";


$count = 0;
while ($count < $total_characters_on_image) { 
$captcha_code .= substr(
    $possible_captcha_letters,
    mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_captcha_letters)-1),
    1);
$count++;
}

$captcha_font_size = $captcha_image_height * 0.65;
$captcha_image = @imagecreate(
    $captcha_image_width,
    $captcha_image_height
    );

/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate(
    $captcha_image,
    255,
    255,
    255
    );

$array_text_color = hextorgb($captcha_text_color);
$captcha_text_color = imagecolorallocate(
    $captcha_image,
    $array_text_color['red'],
    $array_text_color['green'],
    $array_text_color['blue']
    );

$array_noise_color = hextorgb($captcha_noise_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate(
    $captcha_image,
    $array_noise_color['red'],
    $array_noise_color['green'],
    $array_noise_color['blue']
    );

/* Generate random dots in background of the captcha image */
for( $count=0; $count<$random_captcha_dots; $count++ ) {
imagefilledellipse(
    $captcha_image,
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
    2,
    3,
    $image_noise_color
    );
}

/* Generate random lines in background of the captcha image */
for( $count=0; $count<$random_captcha_lines; $count++ ) {
imageline(
    $captcha_image,
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
    $image_noise_color
    );
}

/* Create a text box and add 6 captcha letters code in it */
$text_box = imagettfbbox(
    $captcha_font_size,
    0,
    $captcha_font,
    $captcha_code
    ); 
$x = ($captcha_image_width - $text_box[4])/2;
$y = ($captcha_image_height - $text_box[5])/2;
imagettftext(
    $captcha_image,
    $captcha_font_size,
    0,
    $x,
    $y,
    $captcha_text_color,
    $captcha_font,
    $captcha_code
    );

/* Show captcha image in the html page */
// defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
imagejpeg($captcha_image); //showing the image
imagedestroy($captcha_image); //destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha_code;

function hextorgb ($hexstring){
  $integar = hexdec($hexstring);
  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($integar >> 0x10),
               "green" => 0xFF & ($integar >> 0x8),
               "blue" => 0xFF & $integar);
               }
?>
```

---

**Edit:**

Image of **xampp** software installed on my **Windows 10 64-bit** version:

[xampp softwar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf7bj.png)

Comment: What happens if you navigate to `captcha/captcha.php` directly in the browser? Do you see the image? If not, then do `phpinfo()` do you see entries for `GD Support enabled` and `GD Version bundled`?

Comment: When I go to `captcha/captcha.php` it redirects me to a 404 page and no image is displayed. I have installed the **GD** library through the `php.ini` file in the `xampp\php` path and by putting the `extension=php_gd2.dll` code in the right place and also copying the `php_gd2.dll` file in the `xampp\php` and `xampp\php\ext` paths.I use Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: What is logged in the error.log?

Comment: So that's your issue - 404 means the path is incorrect i.e. src="captcha/captcha.php" needs to point to the actual php file. Are you serving your files on port 80 or something else? It could be you are missing the port number. Or perhaps you're missing a slash, or path e.g "../captcha/captcha.php" if that's not it please post a description/image of your directory structure showing the captcha.php file in relation to submitform.php

Comment: I have placed the `index.php` file, which contains the contact form, in the **main** **root** of my template, and I have also placed the `submitform.php` file in the main **root** of my template, and only the `captcha.php` and monofont.ttf files in a folder named **captcha** I have placed In editing my question, I have included a picture of the **xampp** software that I installed on Windows 10. I don't understand what you mean about the **directory** structure. Is another file required to display the image except the `captcha.php` file?

Comment: Should I create a `.jpeg` file in the **images** folder of my template? Or should I add another **library** to my project? I have found and downloaded this project on the internet, which has worked for many people, but I don't know if others are getting answers on **localhost** or on the **real** **host**?

Comment: I realized where my problem is. I only had to replace `src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/captcha/captcha.php"` with `src="captcha/captcha.php"`. Many thanks for your guidance. Please send me a reply with the code above so I can accept your answer to this important question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake. To display the **captcha** **image** in **WordPress**, I need to specify the path of the captcha file through **WordPress** **codes**.
By replacing the following code instead of the `<img>` tag, the **captcha** **image** will be displayed correctly:

```
<img height="80" width="200" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/captcha/captcha.php"/>
```

Also, in the `<form>` tag and in the **action** section, I should have added a **/** to avoid being redirected to the **404** **page**.